# Netbeans fails to merge because of ignored files

Tags: git, netbeans

I try to merge my git repository with a remote one and what i get is this:

Merge Result: Failed
Merge of HEAD with remote-rep/master failed because of these files:
/path/to/some/file.jpg

The whole folder that file is in is shown as ignored by git. I checked it in .gitignore and it is there. Those files have never been added on commit also.

Comment: Does the file show up when you run `git ls-files`?

Comment: Also try `git ls-tree --name-only remote-rep/master` and see if `/path/to/some/file.jpg` is tracked on the remote branch.  If so, it makes sense that the merge fails even though you don't track it.

Answer (score 2):

The file could have been added by others in the remote repo.
If you really think the file must be ignored, then do this.

1. Move the file (local) to some other location.
2. Merge the remote repo with your master.
3. Untrack the file. `git rm /path/to/some/file.jpg`
4. Commit and Push.
5. Move back your local file to the previous location.
6. Inform your colleagues about this change. ;-)

The best way to avoid this issue is **by committing .gitignore file**. So that everyone shares same .gitignore file.

Comment: I think that doing a `git rm --cached /path/to/some/file.jpg` is easier than that.

Comment: @YuriAlbuquerque: I agree. In case they both are same file (I mean content). `git rm --cached /path/to/some/file.jpg` would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Please try git command in shell instead of the options in Netbeans.
You will see the difference!